# Dealing with databases via python gives wrong results

Tags: python, mysql, sql, database, shell

Is there anything wrong with this method of putting the data into the database?

The part of the program is this. It will be executed several times in a LOOP.

```
    db= MySQLdb.connect("localhost","root","ahmed","practice")
    cursor=db.cursor()

    #checking phase to stop scrapping
    sql = """SELECT Short_link FROM Properties WHERE Short_link=%s"""
    print rows
    rows = cursor.execute(sql,(link_result))
    print rows
    if rows>=1:
        print "Already present - The program is terminating"
        sys.exit()
    else:
        query="""INSERT INTO Properties (Sale_Rent, Type, Title,Price, PricePerSqrFt, Bedroom,Agency_Fee, Bathroom, Size,ZonedFor, Freehold, Prop_ref,Furnished_status,Rent_payment,Building_info,Amenities,Trade_name,Licence, RERA_ID,Phone_info,Short_link) values (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)"""
        cursor.execute(query,(Sale_Rent_result,Type_result, title_result, price_result, Pricepersq_result, bedroom_result, agencyfee_result, bathroom_result, size_result,Zoned_for_result, Freehold_result, propertyref_result, furnished_result, rent_is_paid_result, building_result, Amenities_result, tradename_result, licencenum_result, reraid_result, phone_result, link_result))


    db.commit()
    cursor.close()
    db.close()
```

When I run this program, it runs fine. But when I run 5 copies of this program in a parallel way using the script below, one of the program has row=1 from the start (while the database is empty and row shouldn't be 1).

```
all.sh
python python1.py &
python python2.py &
python python3.py &
python python4.py &
python python5.py &
```

each `link_result's` result is unique after extraction and once its input in the database, it creates a column of unique links.

assuming that the database it empty and i run these files together, `row` should NEVER get equal to 1. it should get 1 when i run the programs again. When i run them again, it will input new data and will stop when the `link_result` conflict with the already present link result (which is checked by the `select` method of sql)

I assume there is some problem with the database opening and closing that the `row` variable gets 1 while the database is empty. I cannot understand such behavior.

This is the whole program for reference

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import MySQLdb
import re
import pdb
import sys





def getting_urls_of_all_pages(): 

    i=1
    while i<=40: #40 is the total number of main pages
        url_rent_flat='http://dubai.dubizzle.com/property-for-rent/residential/apartmentflat/?page='+str(i) #url of the main page (iterating to 40)


        link=[]
        htmlfile=urllib.urlopen(url_rent_flat).read()
        soup=BeautifulSoup(htmlfile)

        link=soup.find_all('a',xtclib=re.compile("listing_list_\d+_title_link"),href=True) #stores all the links (25) links of the page

        """
        Part 2: passing each property url to process for data extraction
        """

        for a in link:
            every_property_in_a_page_data_extraction(a['href']) 

        i+=1


def every_property_in_a_page_data_extraction(url):






    title_result=""
    price_result=""
    bedroom_result="" 
    agencyfee_result="" 
    bathroom_result="" 
    size_result=""
    propertyref_result=""
    furnished_result=""
    rent_is_paid_result=""
    building_result=""
    Amenities_result=""
    tradename_result=""
    licencenum_result=""
    reraid_result=""
    phone_result=""
    link_result=""
    Zoned_for_result=""
    Freehold_result=""
    Pricepersq_result=""
    Type_result="Apartment"
    Sale_Rent_result="Rent"
    rows=0




    """
    Part1: Extracting data
    """

    htmlfile=urllib.urlopen(url).read()
    soup=BeautifulSoup(htmlfile)

    """
    Part2: Extracting the components
    """


    # Sale/Rent
    print "Sale/Rent: ", Sale_Rent_result

    # Type of property
    print "Type of property: ", Type_result

    #title
    try:
        title= soup.find('span',{'id':'listing-title-wrap'})
        title_result= str(title.get_text().strip().encode("utf-8"))
        print "Title: ",title_result
    except StandardError as e:
        title_result="Error was {0}".format(e)
        print title_result

    #price
    try:
        price = soup.find('span',{'id':'actualprice'})
        price_result= str(price.get_text())
        print "Price: ",price_result
    except StandardError as e:
        price_result="Error was {0}".format(e)
        print price_result

    #Agency Fee, Bedroom, Bathroom, Size
    spans_ABBS= []
    for a in soup.select(".important-fields li span"):
        spans_ABBS.append(a.text.strip())

    strongs_ABBS=[]
    for a in soup.select(".important-fields li strong"):
        strongs_ABBS.append(a.text.strip())


    for name, value in zip(spans_ABBS, strongs_ABBS):
        if name=="Agency Fees:":
            try:
                agencyfee_result= str(value)
                print "Agency Fees: ", agencyfee_result
            except StandardError as e:
                agencyfee_result="Error was {0}".format(e)
                print agencyfee_result

        elif name=="Bedrooms:":
            try:
                bedroom_result= str(value)
                print "Number of Bedrooms: ",bedroom_result
            except StandardError as e:
                bedroom_result="Error was {0}".format(e)
                print bedroom_result

        elif name=="Bathrooms:":
            try:
                bathroom_result= str(value)
                print "Number of Bathrooms: ", bathroom_result
            except StandardError as e:
                bathroom_result="Error was {0}".format(e)
                print bathroom_result

        elif name=="Size:":
            try:
                size_result= str(value)
                print "Size of the property: ",size_result
            except StandardError as e:
                size_result="Error was {0}".format(e)
                print size_result

        elif name=="Zoned For:":
            try:
                Zoned_for_result= str(value)
                print "Zoned For:",Zoned_for_result
            except StandardError as e:
                Zoned_for_result="Error was {0}".format(e)
                print Zoned_for_result

        elif name=="Freehold:":
            try:
                Freehold_result= str(value)
                print "Freehold: ",Freehold_result
            except StandardError as e:
                Freehold_result="Error was {0}".format(e)
                print Freehold_result

        elif name=="Price / SqFt:":
            try:
                Pricepersq_result= str(value)
                print "Price Per Sqft: ",Pricepersq_result
            except StandardError as e:
                Pricepersq_result="Error was {0}".format(e)
                print Pricepersq_result

    #Property Reference, Furnished, Listed By, Rent Is Paid, Building, Amenities: 
    spans_others=[]
    for a in soup.select("#listing-details-list li span"):
            spans_others.append(a.text.strip())

    strongs_others=[]
    for a in soup.select("#listing-details-list li strong"):
        strongs_others.append(a.text.strip())



    for name, value in zip(spans_others, strongs_others):
        if name=="Listed by:":
            break

        elif name=="Property Reference:":
            try:
                propertyref_result=str(value.strip())
                print "Property reference in Dubizel: ",propertyref_result
            except StandardError as e:
                propertyref_result="Error was {0}".format(e)
                print propertyref_result

        elif name=="Furnished:":
            try:
                furnished_result=str(value.strip())
                print "Furnished status: ",furnished_result
            except StandardError as e:
                furnished_result="Error was {0}".format(e)
                print furnished_result


        elif name=="Rent Is Paid:":
            try:
                rent_is_paid_result=str(value.strip())
                print "Rent payment: ",rent_is_paid_result
            except StandardError as e:
                rent_is_paid_result="Error was {0}".format(e)
                print rent_is_paid_result

        elif name=="Building:":
            try:
                building_result=str(value.strip())
                print "Building info: ",building_result
            except StandardError as e:
                building_result="Error was {0}".format(e)
                print building_result
        elif name=="Amenities:":
            try:
                for a in value.split(","):
                    Amenities_result+=a.strip()+","
                print Amenities_result
            except StandardError as e:
                Amenities_result="Error was {0}".format(e)
                print Amenities_result



    #Agents info --> TTrade Name, DED Licence Number, RERA Registration Number
    spans_broker=[]
    for a in soup.select("#broker-details li span"):
            spans_broker.append(a.text.strip())

    strongs_broker=[]
    for a in soup.select("#broker-details  li strong"):
        strongs_broker.append(a.text.strip())


    for name, value in zip(spans_broker, strongs_broker):
        if name=="Trade Name:":
            try:
                tradename_result=str(value.strip())
                print "Trade name: ",tradename_result
            except StandardError as e:
                tradename_result="Error was {0}".format(e)
                print tradename_result

        elif name=="DED Licence Number:":
            try:
                licencenum_result=str(value.strip())
                print "Licence #: ",licencenum_result
            except StandardError as e:
                licencenum_result="Error was {0}".format(e)
                print licencenum_result

        elif name=="RERA Registration Number:":
            try:
                reraid_result=str(value.strip())
                print "RERA ID #: ",reraid_result
            except StandardError as e:
                reraid_result="Error was {0}".format(e)
                print reraid_result


    # phone num
    try:
        phone=soup.find_all("div", "phone-content")
        for a in phone:
            phone_result= str(a.get_text().strip().encode("utf-8"))
        print "Phone information:", phone_result
    except StandardError as e:
        phone_result="Error was {0}".format(e)
        print phone_result



    #link
    try:
        link = soup.find('input',{'id':'short-link-input'})
        link_result= str(link.get('value'))
        print "Short Reference link: ", link_result
    except StandardError as e:
        link_result="Error was {0}".format(e)
        print link_result





    """
    Connecting to Database and putting data into in
    """

    db= MySQLdb.connect("localhost","root","ahmed","practice")
    cursor=db.cursor()

    #checking phase to stop scrapping
    sql = """SELECT Short_link FROM Properties WHERE Short_link=%s"""
    print rows
    rows = cursor.execute(sql,(link_result))
    print rows
    if rows>=1:
        print "Already present - The program is terminating"
        sys.exit()
    else:
        query="""INSERT INTO Properties (Sale_Rent, Type, Title,Price, PricePerSqrFt, Bedroom,Agency_Fee, Bathroom, Size,ZonedFor, Freehold, Prop_ref,Furnished_status,Rent_payment,Building_info,Amenities,Trade_name,Licence, RERA_ID,Phone_info,Short_link) values (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)"""
        cursor.execute(query,(Sale_Rent_result,Type_result, title_result, price_result, Pricepersq_result, bedroom_result, agencyfee_result, bathroom_result, size_result,Zoned_for_result, Freehold_result, propertyref_result, furnished_result, rent_is_paid_result, building_result, Amenities_result, tradename_result, licencenum_result, reraid_result, phone_result, link_result))


    db.commit()
    cursor.close()
    db.close()



    #-----------------------------------------------------------





        getting_urls_of_all_pages()
```

Comment: What makes you think your OS won't complete one of your processes before the other one gets to start? At least one of the scripts has already committed the transaction before the other one gets to read from the database.

Comment: each `link_result`'s result is unique in all the 5 programs. assuming that the database it empty and i run these files together, row should NEVER get equal to 1. it should get 1 when i run the programs again. When i run them again, it will input new data and will stop when the link_result conflict with the already present link result (which is checked by the select method of sql)

Comment: Note that `(link_result)` in the `execute()` call is **not** creating a tuple. You want to use `(link_result,)` there.

Comment: You didn't make it clear that `link_result` is supposed to be unique between your scripts; you may want to share how you generate that.

Comment: shared my whole program

Comment: link result is the linnks of the pages, which are unique extraction of the data. this program is actually webscrapping properties link and extracting data and then saving the data into the database

Answer (score 1):

You are not passing `link_result` in to the `execute()` method correctly:

```
rows = cursor.execute(sql,(link_result))
```

The parenthesis are optional there, Python sees this as:

```
rows = cursor.execute(sql, link_result)
```

and thus only the *first character* of `link_result` is used in the query (other databases will tell you you passed in too many parameters).

You need to use a comma to make it a proper tuple:

```
rows = cursor.execute(sql, (link_result,))
```

Comment: one question before i try this code, how can i accept your edits in my questions? i am new here. thanks

Comment: You mean the formatting fixes I made to your question post? I have enough reputation that I can make edits without you needing to accept them.

Comment: i could insert the full links of the `link results` in the database

Comment: the thing is that, the first time the program gets executed, the row should not be 1 until all the programs are terminated. 
Then lets say i run the programs again after 5 mins, some more data will be extracted and the program will be stopped when the new data will conflict the already extracted data (via matching of `link result`'s result

Comment: but in my case, in one of the program (all programs are same except the urls) never gets executed even when the database is empty.

Comment: @user3265370: But when you insert, you are not using a single value, you have *commas* in that expression.

Comment: @user3265370: but when you just started, if *one* of the scripts completed a transaction with a `link_results` value that *starts with the same letter* then other scripts with that same first letter will see the result. Besides, you can also have `link_results` that are error messages, those will certainly not be unique.

Comment: alright. then `rows = cursor.execute(sql, (link_result,))` will solve the problem?

Comment: It will fix the incorrect SQL parameter; it may still cause overlap for error messages.

Comment: can u plz suggest me some other way where i can stop the further extraction when database starts inputting already extracted/inputted data (to fix error message problem)

Comment: then it will be empty and the program will not stop if another copy of that is inserted in the database